# Is there a compatibility table between cometd jar and jetty jar?

Tags: java, jetty, cometd

Is there a compatibility table between cometd jar and jetty jar?

- For example, if I want to upgrade cometd jar from 3.1.3 to 3.1.4 and currently we are using jetty jars of version 9.4.8, what is the recommended version for jetty jar if we upgrade cometd jar?
- Is there compatibility table present?
- What I have tried? - I referred to this [link](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.cometd.java/cometd-java-client/3.1.4/jar) which is maintained by sonatype, there also, there is a version - `<version>${jetty-version}</version>`, but unable to decipher version from this.
- For Maven, we will have to specify jetty version, which is what I am searching for.

Answer (score 3):

CometD 5.0.0 is out, so you want to use that instead of CometD 3.1.x.
Follow the [migration guide](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_migration).

Using CometD 5 will also simplify the dependency with the Jetty jars, since it supports only the Jetty 9.4.x series.

CometD 5.0.0 has been released with a dependency to Jetty 9.4.28, see [here](https://docs.cometd.org/5.0.0/reference/#_requirements_and_dependencies).

It is possible that after a month Jetty releases 9.4.29.
It would be totally fine to not upgrade Jetty and stay with CometD 5.0.0 and Jetty 9.4.28, and wait for the next CometD release.
However, it would be also correct to update your application, keeping CometD 5.0.0 and updating Jetty to 9.4.29.

After a while CometD 5.0.1 is released, for example based on Jetty 9.4.31, and now you update both CometD and Jetty.

The current CometD dependency on Jetty is documented [here](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_requirements_and_dependencies).

The CometD/Java/Jetty table is documented [here](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_preface).